# ghostscript pdf to postscript conversion taking long time

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

I am trying to convert 1000 pages PDF document to postscript file using the below command.

```
gswin32c.exe -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=out.ps -f input.pdf
```

It takes 5 mins to convert, but in real-time, I will have more number of pages than this. I have tried with 30k pages pdf to convert ps using the same command. It takes 45mins.

After search in stack overflow, I have tried the below options of reducing resolution, set buffer memory, threading options, and all. Nothing worked. PF command below.

```
gswin32c.exe -q -r300 -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=out.ps -dNumRenderingThreads=8 -dBufferSpace=2000000000 -f input.pdf
```

dCompressEntireFile option also not helps. Please, anyone, suggest improving the performance of ps conversion with Ghostscript.